# HTML Columns Around Image

Tags: html, multiple-columns

I am trying to get texts in columns to wrap around an image.
I can get it to work when the text is not in columns but when I set to display in 3 columns it just displays beside the image, not beside and bellow.

```
<div id="col" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px">
    <div id="mainhomeimg" style="float:right;">
    <div id="rotator">
    <img src="images/homepage roller/ourwork.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/homepage roller/ourwork.jpg"/>
    </div>
     </div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In posuere felis nec tortor. Pellentesque faucibus. Ut accumsan ultricies elit. Maecenas at justo id velit placerat molestie. Donec dictum lectus non odio. Cras a ante vitae enim iaculis aliquam. Mauris nunc quam, venenatis nec, euismod sit amet, egestas placerat, est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras id elit. Integer quis urna. Ut ante enim, dapibus malesuada, fringilla eu, condimentum quis, tellus. Aenean porttitor eros vel dolor. Donec convallis pede venenatis nibh. Duis quam. Nam eget lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque dignissim congue leo. Mauris vel lacus vitae felis vestibulum volutpat. Etiam est nunc, venenatis in, tristique eu, imperdiet ac, nisl. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In iaculis facilisis massa. Etiam eu urna. Sed porta. Suspendisse quam leo, molestie sed, luctus quis, feugiat in, pede. Fusce tellus. Sed metus augue, convallis et, vehicula ut, pulv</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css

```
.c{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-gap: 20px;
       -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the column count on the containing `div` instead of on the paragraph. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjSBy/)

```
#col {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;    
}
```

This way `#mainhomeimg` is floating inside the element which is set to have columns, and the text of the paragraph will float around it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that however that makes the image appear in the column, not float above it.